# Display Paginated Objects on screen

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, pagination

I have an Array of Objects:

```
const myArray = [
    {myObject: "1"},
    {myObject: "2"},
    {myObject: "3"},
    {myObject: "4"},
    {myObject: "5"},
]
```

I have created a pagination system for this Array of Objects using the following code:

```
function paginator (items, page, per_page) {
    let offset = (page - 1) * per_page;
    let paginatedItems = items.slice(offset).slice(0, per_page);
    let total_pages = Math.ceil(items.length / per_page);

    return {
        page: page,
        per_page: per_page,
        pre_page: page - 1 ? page - 1 : nul,
        next_page: (total_pages > page) ? page + 1 : nul,
        total: items.length,
        total_pages: total_pages,
        data: paginatedItems
    };
}
```

When I have loged the results of this pagination system to the console, it has worked as expected. I now want to display each of the objects in myArray using this pagination system. How could I do this?

I have tried to use the append and append child functions in order to dislpay the objects on screen. I have also looked at multiple different videos and articles and have not been able to find a solution.

Along with the next and previous buttons, I also want to add the numbered buttons to the screen. Each button's inner text should be the page number and should lead to the correct page.

My code:

```
let products = [
    productName: "Brand Name",
    category: "category",
    price: "30",
    image: "images/main_img.jpg",
  },
]
function createCards(products) {
  for (let i of products) {
    //Create Card
    const card = document.createElement("div");
    //Card should have category and should stay hidden initially
    card.classList.add("card", i.category);
    //image div
    const imgContainer = document.createElement("div");
    imgContainer.classList.add("image-container");
    //img tag
    const image = document.createElement("img");
    image.setAttribute("src", i.image);
    imgContainer.appendChild(image);
    card.appendChild(imgContainer);
    //container
    const container = document.createElement("div");
    container.classList.add("container");
    //product name
    const name = document.createElement("h5");
    name.classList.add("product-name");
    name.innerText = i.productName.toUpperCase();
    container.appendChild(name);
    //price
    const price = document.createElement("h6");
    price.innerText = "$" + i.price;
    container.appendChild(price);

    card.appendChild(container);
    document.getElementById("products").appendChild(card);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing the nul->null

I think this will help you

The code is self explanatory

```js
const paginator = (items, page, per_page) => {
  let offset = (page - 1) * per_page;
  let paginatedItems = items.slice(offset).slice(0, per_page);
  let total_pages = Math.ceil(items.length / per_page);

  return {
    page: page,
    per_page: per_page,
    pre_page: page - 1 ? page - 1 : null,
    next_page: (total_pages > page) ? page + 1 : null,
    total: items.length,
    total_pages: total_pages,
    data: paginatedItems
  };
};
const createCard = item => `<div class="card ${item.category}">
  <div class="image-container"><img src="${item.image}" /></div>
  <div class="container">
    <h5 class="product-name">${item.productName.toUpperCase()}</h5>
    <h6>$${item.price}</h6>
  </div>
</div>`;

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const productContainer = document.getElementById("products");
  const buttonContainer = document.getElementById("buttons");
  const prev = document.getElementById("prev");
  const next = document.getElementById("next");
  let currentPage = 1;
  const perPage = 2;
  const lastPage = Math.floor(products.length / perPage) + 1;
  document.getElementById("nav").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (["prev", "next"].includes(tgt.id)) {
      const dir = e.target.id === "next" ? 1 : -1;
      currentPage += dir;
      if (currentPage < 1) currentPage = 1;
      if (currentPage >= lastPage) currentPage = lastPage;
    } else {
      currentPage = +tgt.textContent;
    }
    prev.disabled = currentPage === 1;
    next.disabled = currentPage === lastPage;
    buttonContainer.querySelectorAll('button')
      .forEach((button, i) => button.classList.toggle('active', i === currentPage - 1)); // currentPage starts from 1, i starts from 0
    productContainer.innerHTML = paginator(products, currentPage, perPage)
      .data.map(item => createCard(item)).join("");
  });
  buttonContainer.innerHTML = Array.from({
      length: lastPage
    })
    .map((_, i) => `<button type="button">${i+1}</button>`).join("");
  prev.click(); // start
});
```

```css
.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.card { padding: 5px; width: 80vw; border: 1px dotted black; } 
.image-container { border: 3px solid black; width:100px; height:100px; }
.category1 { background-color: teal; }
.category2 { background-color: yellow; }
.category3 { background-color: pink; }
```

```html
<nav id="nav">
  <button type="button" id="prev">Prev</button>
  <span id="buttons"></span>
  <button type="button" id="next">Next</button>
</nav>
<hr/>
<div id="products"></div>


<script>
  // test data 
  const products = [{
      productName: "Brand Name 1",
      category: "category1",
      price: "30",
      image: "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/fff/000.png&text=Product+1"
    },
    {
      productName: "Brand Name 2",
      category: "category1",
      price: "40",
      image: "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/fff/000.png&text=Product+2"
    },
    {
      productName: "Brand Name 3",
      category: "category1",
      price: "50",
      image: "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/fff/000.png&text=Product+3"
    },
    {
      productName: "Brand Name 4",
      category: "category2",
      price: "60",
      image: "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/fff/000.png&text=Product+4"
    },
    {
      productName: "Brand Name 5",
      category: "category2",
      price: "70",
      image: "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/fff/000.png&text=Product+5"
    },
    {
      productName: "Brand Name 6",
      category: "category3",
      price: "80",
      image: "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/fff/000.png&text=Product+6"
    },
    {
      productName: "Brand Name 7",
      category: "category3",
      price: "90",
      image: "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/fff/000.png&text=Product+7"
    }
  ];
</script>
```